# jquery captcha response no reaction

Tags: jquery, response, captcha

Hi I have a small problem with getting back information from the response with the captcha.

This is my "register script and this works oke.

```
$("#submit_button").click(function()
    {
    // refresh captcha

    if($("#register").valid())
    {       

    $.post("/js/captcha/post.php",$("#register").serialize(),function(response){

    if(response == 1)
            {
            alert("Yep its correct.");
            $("#register").submit();
            //$("#after_submit").html('');
            }
        else
            {
            alert("sorry not correct");         
            change_captcha();
            $("#after_submit").html('');
            }

            });
            // END CHECK CAPTCHA IF OKE GO TO SUBMIT
        }
    });
```

But when i call the `post.php`
it has this information:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(($_REQUEST['code'] == $_SESSION['random_number']) || @strtolower($_REQUEST['code']) == strtolower($_SESSION['random_number']) )
    {
        //echo 1; // submitted 
        echo " Beveiligingscode is correct";

        // Hier include het plaatsen van alle content in de database en dan terug en oke formulier leegmaken.
    }
    else
    {
        echo 0; // invalid code
        echo " Foute beveiligingscode";

    }
    ?>
```

I do get back to the register script but the (response) is always 0.

Hope someone could help.

if you like a life demo check [this](http://www.betav3.gitaartabs.nl/aanmelden.html).

(also i have a strange issue when i use the english script the `button_submit` does not work anymore).

Comment: If I make a bot for this I win. Please hash your captcha before saving it in session.

Comment: Does `var_dump($_SESSION['random_number'])` match what `$_REQUEST['code']` is?

Comment: problem solved i have echo 0; what is correct but also the echo "foute beveiligingscode is correct" this is not good because the response gives not only the 0 or 1 but also the text message back.